# Invalid links are not redirecting to 404 page, may be .htaccess issue

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to re-direct invalid links to 404 page but not happening. for example:- localhost/project1/complaints/category-is-here.html
 now the "category-is-here.html" doesn't exist and it should be re-direct to 404 page.

but instead of redirecting to 404 error. 
This page showing the text "category-is-here.html" in the page.

if i randomly change the name in browser such as:-
localhost/project1/complaints/category145asdsa-is-here(whatever i typed in link).html

it shows new text "**category145asdsa-is-here(whatever i typed in link).html**" in the page instead of redirecting to 404 page.

```
htaccess

RewriteEngine on

ErrorDocument 404 /page-not-found.html

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^complaints/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)-(.*).html$            complaint-info.php?ticket-number=$4

RewriteRule ^complaints/(.*)/(.*)$   complaint-listing.php?sub-category=$2
RewriteRule ^complaints/(.*)$   sub-listing.php?category=$1
RewriteRule ^page-not-found.html$            404.php
```

i hope you'll understand my problem.

kind regards
dev